# identifier “atomicAdd” is undefined using cuda 6

Tags: cuda

I am a newbie in programming Cuda, so this might not be the only question about it. I am running code on Cuda 6.0 but I have code with atomic function `atomicAdd`, are these functions supported by this version of toolkit ? Since it keeps showing me an error

> Identifier "atomicAdd" is not defined

Comment: They are supported, but not for all datatypes! Can you show a [mcve] for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also indicate what GPU you are running on and what is your compile command exactly.

Comment: here is the example i tried to run : https://github.com/udacity/cs344/blob/master/Lesson%20Code%20Snippets/Lesson%203%20Code%20Snippets/histo.cu

Comment: @Emad, perhaps you've forgotten to `#include  <device_atomic_functions.h>`?

Comment: @einpoklum you don't need to include that header file when compiling with `nvcc`

Comment: i compile it using the following command and it works : nvcc -arch=sm_35 -v